# Postfix 2nd domain

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, smtp, bind

I have two postfix servers(virtual machines) on same host

1st domain = mail.xyz.org

2nd domain = mail.xyz.edu

I want to send mail from 1st domain to 2nd domain.

If i try, it gives error:
**Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table**

1st domain main.cf file

````
# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 3.6 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 3.6



# TLS parameters
#relay_clientcerts = hash:/etc/postfix/clientcerts
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/mail_signed_cert.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/mailkey.pem
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_tls_clientcerts, reject_unauth_destination
#smtpd_tls_ask_ccert = yes

#smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
#smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
#tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom

smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_key_file = /home/ca_certs/client_certs/key.pem
smtp_tls_cert_file = /home/ca_certs/client_certs/signed_cert.pem
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/cacert.pem
smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/postfix
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt

#smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
#smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
#smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3

#smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
#smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
#smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
#smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
#smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

#smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mail.xyz.org
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = mail.xyz.org, localhost.xyz.org, localhost, mail.xyz.edu, xyz.edu
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104, [::1]/128, 192.168.1.0/24
mailbox_command = 
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
home_mailbox = Maildir/
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 3
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes```
````